# Write a file in android?

Tags: android

I get my raw resource:

> InputStream myRawResource =
>   context.getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(myID);

How can I write this to a file? An MP3 file on the device.

Comment: a simple search on the website and you find your happyness : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=write+a+file+android+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
  {
  File f=new File("myFile.mp3");
  InputStream myRawResource = context.getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(myID);   
  OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
  byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
  int len;
  while((len=myRawResource.read(buf))>0)
  out.write(buf,0,len);
  out.close();
  myRawResource.close();
  System.out.println("\nFile is created........
...........................");
  }
  catch (IOException e){}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and normal Java file ops.